# How to bind to the class itself in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using the code below to bind to the `Depth` property of a the `ColumnSection` class. And I'm using the `LengthConverter` to return an arbitrary result.

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Depth"
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path= Depth, Converter={StaticResource LengthConverter}}"
                Width="60" />
```

Now what if I wanted to bind to the `ColumnSection` class itself? I will then use a converter to return the Width/Depth ratio and display it as a result. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use the "." path:

```
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=., Converter={...}}"
```

"." maps to the current data context.

As it turns out, you can even do these, since the *default* path is ".":

```
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Converter={...}}"
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding}" //No converter obviously
```

I like my original the best, as it is the most explicit and understandable.